# 2's complement in shellscript

Tags: bash, binary, twos-complement

I am trying to create a simple program in Shellscript(Bash) to calculate 2's complement binary numbers.

As a test, I am only using an 8-bit binary value (00000100) but I keep getting a "Bad Substitution" error and I have no idea why.

```
  #!/bin/bash
binary=00000100
firstBit=${binary:0:1}
secondBit=${binary:1:1}
thirdBit=${binary:2:1}
fourthBit=${binary:3:1}
fifthBit=${binary:4:1}
sixthBit=${binary:5:1}
seventhBit=${binary:6:1}
eighthBit=${binary:7:1}
binaryNew=""
if [[ $firstBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew=0
if [[ $secondBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else 
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $thirdBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $fourthBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $fifthBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $sixthBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $seventhBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
if [[ $eighthBit == "1" ]]
then
binaryNew+=0
else
binaryNew+=1
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
echo $binaryNew=
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting the error, just `=` as output, as the first bit is 0, so all the rest of the ifs (you should indent the code properly) is skipped.

Comment: Run your code with `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: @choroba I get a bad substitution error using my available Shellscript server. It doesn't seem to like something in that script but I cannot tell what. 

On your second point: How can I handle the first if statement to move onto the second number if the first one is 0? 

Obviously, "=" isn't the response I am looking for

Comment: @MrDigs, I've posted an aswer about "bad substitution" because it is too long to be a comment. I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 5):

To do two's complement on an 8-bit binary value:

```
$ binary=00000100
$ x=$((2#$binary))
$ [ "$x" -gt 127 ] && ((x=x-256)); echo "$x"
4
```

#### Notes

1. The expression `$((2#$binary))` does conversion from binary to decimal.
2. The commands `[ "$x" -gt 127 ] && ((x=x-256))` perform two's complement on an 8-bit value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over a value, use a loop instead of defining a variable for each position:

```
#! /bin/bash

binary=0100
for ((pos=0 ; pos < ${#binary} ; pos++ )) ; do
    if (( ${binary:$pos:1} )) ; then
        complement+=0
    else
        complement+=1
    fi
done
echo $complement
```

Comment: I think you need double parentheses around `((complement+=1))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: No, I'm not adding 1, I'm concatenating the strings. I've tested the script before posting.

Comment: My apologies, I see now. I guess I would have used `complement+="1"` for strings.

Comment: You cold replace the contents of the whole loop with `complement+=$((${binary:pos:1} ? 0 : 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

With bash, tr and bc:

```
#!/bin/bash

binary=00000100

# Ones' complement, result decimal
c1=$(tr 01 10 <<< $binary)

# Two's complement, result decimal
c2=$((2#$c1+1))

# convert decimal to binary
echo "obase=2; $c2" | bc
```

Output:

```
11111100
```

Answer (score 2):

I will *not* answer how to calculate 2's complement in bash.
Instead I will answer why the OP's getting the 'Bad substitution' error.

Note the two spaces before the shebang:

```
  #!/bin/bash
```

Because of these, it's not interpreted as a shebang, but as a usual line with a comment indented by two spaces.

Because of that, the script is not executed by bash, but by user's default shell, in OP's case it's most likely `/bin/sh` or whatever it is symlinked to.

You can determine what shell is used by the user as default how suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059152/8868289):

```
getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f7
```

Answer (score 1):

for arithmetic operation in bash use double parenthesis `((` .. `))`, otherwise some operation can be done if variable declared as integer.

```
typeset -i binaryNew
binaryNew+=1
```

or

```
((binaryNew+=1))
```

bash arithmetic can only convert from a base between 2 to 62 to base 10, for example

```
i=$((2#10101))
echo "$i"
```